# Python subprocess.Popen return code after killing with signal

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen, exit-code

Consider the following code:

```
SIGNAL = 123
proc = subprocess.Popen("longrunning")
proc.send_signal(SIGNAL)
```

Now what I want is to get the exit code that has been returned from the code with `exit()`.

Unfortunately, in Python I get only the signal number that the process was stopped with:

```
>>> proc.returncode == -SIGNAL
True
```

Comment: What OS supports signal 123?

Comment: @stark nevermind, that's just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are mutually exclusive. If you process is terminated as a result of getting a signal it won't get a chance to produce a return code with `exit()`.

See `man 2 waitpid` for explanation on the underlying system call mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if the program handles the signal and `exit`s manually, then it means that it was not terminated by a signal?

Comment: Correct, from OS perspective the signal has been handled and the program decided to exit by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
proc = subprocess.call(["ls", "-alh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc
0
```

subprocess.call ends up calling Popen but I've found it's a bit less complicated to use.

source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html